# hadoop - HDFS file distribution

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I just started to play with Hadoop and I'm having the following doubt:
We know well that the Namenode has "MetaData" information about the input blocks. Now my questions are:

1. How can I view or query the metadata?
2. How can I see - how my input file is blocked and distributed?
3. How can I make sure that my input file is blocked and distributed in the HDFS?

**PS:** I have referred the following site already:

http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How can I view or query the metadata?

   You can do that with the help of **Offline Image Viewer**. It is a tool to dump the contents of **fsimage** files to human-readable formats in order to allow offline analysis and examination of an Hadoop cluster's namespace.

   **Usage :**

   **bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.txt**

   You can find more on this **[here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html)**.
2. How can I see - how my input file is blocked and distributed?

   Easiest way would be to point your web browser to **HDFS webUI**, i.e **namemnode_machine:50070**. Then browse to the file in question and click to open it. Scroll down and you can see the location of each block of this file.

   Alternatively, you can use **getFileBlockLocations(FileStatus file, long start, long len)** provided by **FileSystem API**. It return an array containing hostnames, offset and size of portions of the given file.
3. How can I make sure that my input file is blocked and distributed in the HDFS?

   You can use **fsck** to do that. It will show you all the necessary stuff, like **Total blocks, Minimally replicated blocks, Under-replicated blocks** etc related to a particular file.

Comment: Hi .. when i execute this bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.txt im getting nullpointer exception

Comment: Hi..could u plz provide me some more detail?

Comment: when i execute this bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.txt , im getting an empty "fsimage.txt" o/p file

Answer (score 0):

Namenode's metadata is stored in a file called "fsimage". You can go through the below link for your reference

[Content of the fsimage hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779501/content-of-the-fsimage-hdfs)